# Buggish behavior of a UILabel Text when selecting a Custom built UITableViewCell: the text get mixup or overlaid with a previously loaded label

Tags: iphone, uitableview, text, uilabel

I have been looking for a solution to this issue for a few days now... and cannot find someone with a similar problem or a solution that would work for me. At this point I am not even sure that I am doing something wrong, as I have read and analyzed many sample code and I am almost 100% sure that I am doing this the way it should...

Anyway here it comes:

I have a UITableView to which I display custom built UITableViewCell, here is where I create them:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
                               reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    CGRect textViewRect = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 250, 25);
    UILabel *textView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:textViewRect];

    textView.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textView.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];


    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(270.0, 15, 16, 16);
    UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];

    icon.image = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"color-icon"];
    icon.highlightedImage = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"gray-icon"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:icon];
    [icon release];
}
```

So as you can see, pretty standard stuff... Then when I click on one of the cell, another view gets loaded instead of the table.
Until now, everything is fine, but then when I come back to that table view and that it has to reload the problem starts...

By the way I have added this to the delegate methods so the cells never stay selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // [...] a lot more code here 
}
```

When I clicked on my cell in the simulator with the mouse and keep it down the cell stays selected as expected (same way on the device itself) and this is why I get:

[Image 1]

The UILabel Text is totally mixed up ! The screenshot is actually of the last cell of the table and the overlapping text is the one of the first cell. And the behavior on the first is similar, if I maintain the click on it, it will show the same behavior mixing up with the UILabel text of the last cell. I am guessing that is is due to the way the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` works (probably a FILA queue).

Of course I tried to work around that and found some really weird stuff.

If I don't click the cells are perfect, no bugs, the correct text is displayed etc:

[Image 2]

Then I tried to mess up a little bit with the parameters of my UILabel. I added this:

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And when I do this, as soon as the table reload, then I don't even need to highlight the cell to see the screw up behavior:

[Image 3]

The only way I was about to get rid of the problem to always instantiate a new cell rather than dequeueing one...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
                               reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

was replaced by:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
                               reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

But of course this won't work on the long term because of the memory leak...

Also, it is to be noted that I have the exact same behavior for another UITableView in another view somewhere in this App... The other custom cell is more complex, more labels, more images, etc, but all the label exhibit the same behavior. And this more complex Table View is managed by a Navigation Controller, so no custom loading / unloading like the first one...

That's all I have, and I can't find a solution... please help !

Arghh this is really annoying... I am new so I cannot post images... :(
Here is a link where you can see the referenced images: https://skitch.com/aponsin/rne9k/fullscreen.png-100-layer-3-rgb-8

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create new label and add it to cell each time cell is being reused. To fix that you must create your label only when your cell is created:

```
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
                               reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    CGRect textViewRect = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 250, 25);
    UILabel *textView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:textViewRect];
    textView.tag = kLabelTag;
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textView.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];


    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(270.0, 15, 16, 16);
    UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];

    icon.image = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"color-icon"];
    icon.highlightedImage = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"gray-icon"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:icon];
    [icon release];
}
```

And after that you can get your label from cell using tag property you've assigned:

```
UILabel *textView = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kLabelTag];
textView.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

same logic also applies to setting up your icon imageview if it varies in different cells

Also have a look at components standard UITableViewCell already provides (depending on its cell style) - there's already UIImageView and UILabels there and you can set your custom properties to them and use them without creating extra components

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast, but that really does not work for me. I added the tag and tried to retrieve the label from the view with the tag if it reuses a previous cell. And some cell seems to work fine, but other have "black-out" label. And player around with the table will quickly give a SegF with a "message sent to deallocated instance 0x69210c0". It sounds normal to me that this doesn't work as I am release all the label anyways... but I am a newby in iOS dev... so I am surely missing something

Comment: How woah... ok found the pb, I don't know how I missed that... You were right Vladimir, sorry for my misunderstanding. I don't even need to use the tags, I never realized that I was not supposed to re-create the cell every time. That the identifier was smart enough to know it was the correct cell rather that the same "cell type". I basically should only create my subviews once if cell == nil and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It makes much more sense now :)